# Does the license for arXiv uploads apply to TeX source or the PDF?

Tags: arxiv, preprint, latex, license, creative-commons

I am wondering to which of the content that I publish on arXiv the license I chose during publication applies.

Let's assume that I uploaded just a single TeX-source file and filled out the form with metadata (Title, Tags, Keywords, Abstract).
Then, I have different licenses to choose from, see https://arxiv.org/help/license

At the moment of writing, there are

- [CC BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/): Creative Commons Attribution
- [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/): Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike
- [CC BY-NC-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/): Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike
- [CC BY-NC-ND](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/): Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-NoDerivatives
- [arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/)
- [CC Zero](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/)

After publication, arXiv compiles a PDF and makes it available on the articles page for download. The preprint's arXiv page then features links to the PDF, Postscript, "Other formats" (including the TeX-source), and a link to the license:

Like this

[image: arxiv-license]

or this

[image: CC-BY]

## To which files/artifacts does the chosen license apply?

### Only the TeX-source?

What license then applies to the PDF-file? In the case of a TeX-source published under, e.g., a CC-BY license, does the PDF give the proper attribution?

> a. ***Attribution.***
>
> 1. If You Share the Licensed Material (including in modified form), You must:
>
>    A. retain the following if it is supplied by the Licensor with the Licensed Material:
>
>    i. identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material and any others designated to receive attribution, in any reasonable
>    manner requested by the Licensor (including by pseudonym if
>    designated);
>
>    ii. a copyright notice;
>
>    iii. a notice that refers to this Public License;
>
>    iv. a notice that refers to the disclaimer of warranties;
>
>    v. a URI or hyperlink to the Licensed Material to the extent reasonably practicable;
>
>    B. indicate if You modified the Licensed Material and retain an indication of any previous modifications; and
>
>    C. indicate the Licensed Material is licensed under this Public License, and include the text of, or the URI or hyperlink to, this
>    Public License.

Assuming that I did not only upload TeX-source but also some images, I would assume that all my "uploads" are subject to the chosen license.

### Only the PDF-file?

Which license then applies to the TeX-Source? Under which terms could I, e.g., copy parts of the published TeX-source code (e.g. tikz-code graphics) and remix/republish it in one of my own works?

### TeX-Source and PDF-file?

Comment: "Funny" thing: if you click on the support page *https://arxiv.org/help/license/contact#contacting-arxiv* ... there is a 404 error .

Comment: I always assumed the same license applied to both.  AFAIK arXiv has no way to specify separate licenses for source and PDF, neither for the author nor for the reader.  I also can't think of any reason why anyone should *want* to release them under different licenses, nor any reason why arXiv should support them in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

This is not to be taken as legal advice regarding your specific situation. For specific advice regarding your legal risk, please consult your lawyer or representation.

The license applies to the [whole of the content uploaded to arXiv](https://info.arxiv.org/help/policies/submission_agreement.html#grant-of-the-license-to-arxiv), as explained in the [Submission terms and agreement](https://info.arxiv.org/help/policies/submission_agreement.html).

The "arXiv license" is the minimal rights required by arXiv to distribute your work, and it applies to the whole of the source package. It does not grant subsequent rights to others (which things like the various CC licenses may). Individual files within the package may have differing licenses (e.g. some tex packages may contain a compatible MIT license, which is different than the arXiv license). If your work is licensed under a specific license that is not available in the list of licenses from arXiv, you can select the arXiv license and then specify the license within the full text of the article (e.g. a Open Access license that is not one of the CC licenses).

Answer (score 2):

Almost all common licenses, including CC licenses are about *content*, not format. Even the ND versions have this in the description:

> Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format

Note "any medium or format".

There must be some, perhaps for video, that allow distribution but not alteration (think video streaming), but that wouldn't be typical for a license to academic work.

And note that the arXiv license is a license from the copyright holder to arXiv itself so that the work can't be withdrawn. It is not a license to others.